Is it possible to use Spring-Boot 3 / Micrometer @Observed annotation on methods without that Observation generating a metric for the method?
We're running into the problem where we want to use @Observed annotations to create tracing spans for methods in our code, which is helpful, but it is less-helpful that Micrometer seems to generate a metric for each of these methods as well (to track performance I guess?).
Does anyone know of a way to tell micrometer to just use Observations for tracing or just for metrics vs the current default behavior of "both"?

The Observation API by default does not record metrics nor spans. You need to register handlers to record anything. This is the "superpower" of the API, you decide runtime what outputs you want. I recommend watching this talk from beginning to end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qyku6cR6ADY#t=14m23s
Spring Boot on the other hand registers handlers for you based on your classpath: if micrometer-core is present, it will register DefaultMeterHandler to record metrics, if Micrometer Tracing is on the classpath, it will register tracing handlers.
In order to prevent registration of DefaultMeterHandler, you can do a few things:

Exclude micrometer-core from your classpath
Disable the auto-configuration class that creates the handler
Create your own ObservationRegistry and register your own handler

Btw why do you want to publish spans but not metrics?
